# ls command: what does the first line mean?

Tags: shell, ls

When I do `ls -l` I get this:

```
calico@A000505:~/Documentos$ ls -l
total 2020
-rwxr-xr-x 1 calico calico    8559 2010-11-16 11:12 a.out
-rwxrw-rw- 1 smt    smt    2050138 2010-10-14 10:40 Java2.pdf
-rwxrw-rw- 1 ocv    ocv        234 2010-11-16 11:11 test.c
```

But what does the "total 2020" mean? I only have 3 files so it's not the number of files or directories, and I guess it's not the size either. So what is it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The number of 1kB blocks *used* by the files in the directory, non-recursively.

Use `ls -lh` to have some more meaningful output.

Comment: More precisely, on most implementations, this is the total number of blocks used by files included in the directory listing (compare `ls -l ~` with `ls -la ~`, and `ls -lA ~`). The block size is 1kB with GNU tools, but 512B according to POSIX and most other current implementations.

Comment: What does `-h` do?

Answer (score 17):

**what does "total" mean in ls -al**

Great question, it means you want to pay attention to detail.  I'll illustrate with examples.  Under my home directory `/home/el` there is a directory called tmpdir with files underneath it.  I change to that directory and do `ls -al`

```
el@angeliqe ~/tmpdir $ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 4 el users 4096 Dec 21 11:45 .
drwx--x--x 9 el users 4096 Dec 21 11:45 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 el users 4096 Dec 21 11:45 dirWithFiles
drwxrwxr-x 2 el users 4096 Dec 21 11:44 emptydir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 el users  182 Dec 21 11:45 myfile.txt
```

It says 'total 20'.  That translates to: "tmpdir uses 20K of space on disk for all of the directories and files".

with the -h option, you tell it to give it to you in human readable form:

```
el@angeliqe ~/tmpdir $ ls -alh
total 20K
drwxrwxr-x 4 el users 4.0K Dec 21 11:45 .
drwx--x--x 9 el users 4.0K Dec 21 11:45 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 el users 4.0K Dec 21 11:45 dirWithFiles
drwxrwxr-x 2 el users 4.0K Dec 21 11:44 emptydir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 el users  182 Dec 21 11:45 myfile.txt
```

It is interesting to note that a directory with nothing in it also takes up 8K space, in my case `emptydir` has nothing in it but shows as using 8K

```
el@angeliqe ~/tmpdir/emptydir $ ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 el users 4096 Dec 21 11:44 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 el users 4096 Dec 21 11:45 ..
```

Adding an empty directory proves that directories take up 4K:

```
el@angeliqe ~/tmpdir/emptydir $ ls -alh
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x 3 el users 4.0K Dec 21 11:54 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 el users 4.0K Dec 21 11:45 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 el users 4.0K Dec 21 11:54 blah
```

Another command to investigate is `du`:

```
el@angeliqe ~/tmpdir/emptydir $ du
4       ./blah
8       .
```

Also, you can look at file sizes to a certain depth:

```
el@angeliqe ~ $ du -h --max-depth=1
12K     ./.ssh
4.0K    ./my_recycle_bin
8.0K    ./.vim
13G     ./gnuoctbluehost
24K     ./tmpdir
48K     ./.subversion
152K    ./.cpan
13G     .
el@angeliqe ~ $
```

Comment: K refers to kilobyte or kibibyte?

Answer (score 6):

Nobody mention about `-s` option(?). From `man ls`:

`-s, --size
              print the allocated size of each file, in blocks`

.. so if you list with `ls -s` then you will get number of blocks for each directory and file in current directory. When you summarize it then you will get exactly the same number as in `total:` you see on top of `ls -l`.

Extra: To get block size check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/121252/how-do-i-find-the-hardware-block-read-size-for-my-hard-drive).