# Total in `ls -l`

Tags: osx, ls

When I run `ls -l`, the following is displayed:

```
>: ls -l
total 320
-rw-r--r--   1 foo  staff    633  5 Apr 13:23 A.class
-rw-r--r--   1 foo  staff    296  5 Apr 13:24 A.java
...
```

What does the `total` signify? Size? If so, what size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ls command: what does the first line mean?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4109/ls-command-what-does-the-first-line-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man 1 ls` on Mac OS X 10.6.7, specifically the section titled "The Long Format"

```
In addition, for each directory whose contents are
displayed, the total number of 512-byte blocks used by the files in the directory is
displayed on a line by itself, immediately before the information for the files in
the directory.
```

Answer (score 6):

It's the total number of blocks (usually 512 bytes per POSIX; see `man ls` for details of the `$BLOCKSIZE` environment variable) as obtained from the `st_blocks` and `st_blocksize` elements of the `stat()` structure for each file.  As such, it is not recursive and not bloated by "sparse" files.