# SSH Permission Denied Public Key

Tags: ssh

I'm not able to ssh to remote host. This was happening before but I'm not able to figure out what has changed in the past couple of days.

I tried debugging and this is the debug output

```
    OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.34.109.199" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.34.109.199 [10.34.109.199] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.34.109.199:22 as 'aditya.natarajan'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/dev/null"
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:FPlu50ts83bXVxf5oPNO40oS5u+WdOjVsY4m4NGm51E
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/dev/null"
Warning: Permanently added '10.34.109.199' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f9640e02930)
debug2: key: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:H9btpHW7BB+2wqUGY33pLe2zUnTH+LJeU8wEAzxWQTY
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:H9btpHW7BB+2wqUGY33pLe2zUnTH+LJeU8wEAzxWQTY
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/aditya.natarajan/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

This is the successful login debug output by a different user

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1  
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config  
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *  
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 103: Applying options for *  
debug2: resolving "10.34.109.199" port 22  
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0  
debug1: Connecting to 10.34.109.199 [10.34.109.199] port 22.  
debug1: Connection established.  
debug1: identity file /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_rsa type 1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_dsa type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1  
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0  
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2  
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2  
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000  
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK  
debug1: Authenticating to 10.34.109.199:22 as 'gaurav.prasad'  
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/known_hosts"  
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/known_hosts:453  
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.34.109.199  
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa  
debug3: send packet: type 20  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent  
debug3: receive packet: type 20  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received  
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal  
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c  
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519  
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc  
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc  
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1  
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1  
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib  
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib  
debug2: languages ctos:  
debug2: languages stoc:  
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  
debug2: reserved 0  
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal  
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1  
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256  
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se  
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se  
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96  
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96  
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com  
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com  
debug2: languages ctos:  
debug2: languages stoc:  
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  
debug2: reserved 0  
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256  
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa  
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none  
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none  
debug3: send packet: type 30  
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT  
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY  
debug3: receive packet: type 31  
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:tXH70uT2Fsp4oquBhCbnSfuH0xdYTr0M4LX7uhjhmu0  
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/known_hosts"  
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/known_hosts:453  
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.34.109.199  
debug1: Host '10.34.109.199' is known and matches the RSA host key.  
debug1: Found key in /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/known_hosts:453  
debug3: send packet: type 21  
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1  
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent  
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS  
debug3: receive packet: type 21  
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0  
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received  
debug2: key: /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fd3f1f00600)  
debug2: key: /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)  
debug2: key: /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)  
debug2: key: /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)  
debug3: send packet: type 5  
debug3: receive packet: type 6  
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received  
debug3: send packet: type 50  
debug3: receive packet: type 51  
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey  
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey  
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password  
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey  
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password  
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey  
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey  
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_rsa  
debug3: send_pubkey_test  
debug3: send packet: type 50  
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply  
debug3: receive packet: type 60  
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279  
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:QmBK5AxNY234TdAkcDhM2pO8X8ip4irvMae0AyygbnA  
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:QmBK5AxNY234TdAkcDhM2pO8X8ip4irvMae0AyygbnA  
debug2: storing passphrase in keychain  
debug3: Search for existing item with query: {  
    acct = "/Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_rsa";  
    agrp = "com.apple.ssh.passphrases";  
    class = genp;  
    labl = "SSH: /Users/gaurav.prasad/.ssh/id_rsa";  
    nleg = 1;  
    "r_Ref" = 1;  
    svce = OpenSSH;  
}  
debug3: Item already exists in the keychain, updating.  
debug3: send packet: type 50  
debug3: receive packet: type 52  
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).  
Authenticated to 10.34.109.199 ([10.34.109.199]:22).  
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]  
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0  
debug2: channel 0: send open  
debug3: send packet: type 90  
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com  
debug3: send packet: type 80  
debug1: Entering interactive session.  
debug1: pledge: network  
debug3: receive packet: type 91  
debug2: callback start  
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY  
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10  
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0  
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1  
debug3: send packet: type 98  
debug1: Sending environment.  
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM  
debug3: Ignored env TERM  
debug3: Ignored env SHELL  
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE  
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR  
debug3: Ignored env DOCKER_HOST  
debug3: Ignored env GRADLE_HOME  
debug3: Ignored env Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render  
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION  
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID  
debug3: Ignored env HISTFILESIZE  
debug3: Ignored env USER  
debug3: Ignored env HBASE_HOME  
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK  
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING  
debug3: Ignored env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY  
debug3: Ignored env MAVEN_HOME  
debug3: Ignored env PATH  
debug3: Ignored env PWD  
debug3: Ignored env JAVA_HOME  
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_PROFILE  
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS  
debug3: Ignored env HISTIGNORE  
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL  
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME  
debug3: Ignored env DOCKER_CERT_PATH  
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL  
debug3: Ignored env HOME  
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_SESSION_ID  
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME  
debug3: Ignored env RABBITMQ_HOME  
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8  
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0  
debug3: send packet: type 98  
debug3: Ignored env PROMPT_COMMAND  
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY  
debug3: Ignored env HISTTIMEFORMAT  
debug3: Ignored env _  
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1  
debug3: send packet: type 98  
debug2: callback done  
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768  
debug3: receive packet: type 99  
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0  
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0  
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152  
debug3: receive packet: type 99  
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0  
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0  
Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u2 x86_64  

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;  
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the  
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.  

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent  
permitted by applicable law.  
Last login: Wed Oct 12 15:05:51 2016 from 172.20.52.62  
gaurav.prasad@prod-europa-secondary953-361171:~$ hostname -i  
10.34.109.199
```

But my keys are present in .ssh and permissions seem alright. Or am I missing something?

```
ls -alF .ssh/
    total 168
    drwx------   8 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users    272 Oct  7 17:36 ./
    drwxr-xr-x+ 81 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users   2754 Oct  7 17:41 ../
    -rw-------   1 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users   3327 Mar  1  2016 co-user
    -rw-------   1 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users    734 Mar  1  2016 co-user.pub
    -rw-------   1 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users     75 Sep 29 19:42 config
    -rw-------   1 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users   1766 Jul  8  2015 id_rsa
    -rw-------   1 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users    417 Jul  8  2015 id_rsa.pub
    -rw-------   1 aditya.natarajan  FKIPL\Domain Users  64233 Sep 29 17:55 known_h
```

Comment: I don't see an authorized keys file, and the server appears to only accept key authentication.

Comment: @JeffSchaller This directory listing if from the local host, authorized_keys must not be present there. The server already accepted the key from `id_rsa`, but the corresponding public key may not be in the authorized_keys on the server.

Comment: The keys are rejected. What messages can you see in the server log? What is the key you intend to authenticate with?

Comment: is this .ssh directory really located at `/Users/aditya.natarajan/`? or somewhere else?

Comment: see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/268776/how-do-i-configure-ssh-so-it-dosent-try-all-the-identity-files-automatically/436015#436015), might be something to do with having so many files in .ssh (168). Maybe can solve it by reducing the number or by setting `IdentitiesOnly=yes` option along with `IdentityFile` in your ssh config.

Comment: @Jakuje I don't have access to the server log since I can't connect to the machine. I didn't get your second question

Comment: @gogoud that is not 168 files; see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4109/117549

Comment: @Jakuje where (path )do i check the server log?

Comment: `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: it says connection closed by (preauth){my ip}

Comment: I've added successful login debug output by my peer.

Comment: If you get access to the server, make sure that the identity file (often /~/.ssh/authorized_keys) has the right permissions set so that only you can read it. If not, run chmod 600 on it.

Comment: @M_dk My permission on server was -rw-------. Seems alright.
Anyway, I've solved the issue by deleting my ~/.ssh in local and regenerating key pair. But I still don't understand why this issue happened in the first place when I don't remember changing anything

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with the public key in authorized_keys in the server because I'm able to ssh now with another id whose public key hasn't changed ( before and after clearing my ~/.ssh folder in local). It's something to do with the folder ~/.ssh or some other ssh issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: @rattleTrap  Did you check permissions on the .ssh folder too?

Comment: It was -drwx---------