# How to do a Cron.d permission review to ensure sensitive files and directories are secured?

Tags: linux, rhel, cron

Did an extraction for Linux system audit and is quite confused over the results. If I want to review the cron.d which line should i really be looking at?

```
/etc/cron.d:
total 20
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   61 Jun 10 05:11 .
drwxr-xr-x. 92 root root 8192 Sep 20 09:31 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  128 Nov  1  2018 0hourly
-rw-------.  1 root root  235 Jun 20  2018 sysstat
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   49 Jun 10 05:11 vpfs_monitor.cron
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4109/ls-command-what-does-the-first-line-mean

Comment: You seem to be distracted by or focused on the "total 20" in the output. It's not clear what relation that has to cron or auditing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ls command: what does the first line mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4109/ls-command-what-does-the-first-line-mean)

Comment: hi all, have edited the "total 20" to really focus on auditing cron.d

Comment: what do you mean by "extraction" and "audit"?   what are you trying to find out?  without that, it's impossible to even guess "which line you should really be looking at", or if any of the lines above even contain the information you want.

Comment: i supposed this were the results when /etc/cron.d was run, so what do all the line item mean?